# Converting Binary To Dec

Tags: binary, decimal

This is the program I have written so far but I'm having trouble executing the error statement to appear.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryToDec {
    public static void main(String []args ) {
            String binary;
            int dec;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a binary number: ");
            binary = scan.nextLine();


            dec = Integer.parseInt(binary,2);
                System.out.printf("The corresponding decimal value is: %d\n",dec);

                System.out.println("Invalid binary number entered!");

    }
}
```

The two examples it has to properly print out are put
Enter a binary number: 1000100
The corresponding decimal value is: 68

Enter a binary number: 12345
Invalid binary number entered!

Comment: Well, what is the result of `parseInt` if it fails to parse?  *mmmm?*

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12345"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at BinaryToDec.main(BinaryToDec.java:23)

Comment: thats the error message I get when I try the binary input: 12345

Comment: well then, it sounds like you need to create a Try-Catch statement which looks for that Exception, and tada! Problem solved, no?

Comment: That worked perfectly but now here's the tricky part reading the binary as a string and using a loop to go through each individual digit

Comment: Thats not hard at all, if you have an issue, just post it here and someone will be able to assist you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass in the wrong information into: `Integer.parseInt(string)` you will get a NumberFormatException.

```
try{
  dec = Integer.parseInt(binary,2);
  System.out.printf("The corresponding decimal value is: %d\n", dec);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  System.out.println("Invalid Binary Number Entered!");
}
```

would solve it.  Then depending on what you are trying to do, add it to a loop to ask again, or you can just Exit the application.